# WPF: RadialGradientBrush without gradient?

Tags: wpf, radial-gradients

I want to draw some circles in another circle like this:

[alt text http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/6379/circles.png](http://img38.imageshack.us/img38/6379/circles.png)

Is there a way to tell a RadialGradientBrush not to use gradients but just fixed colors, so I can achieve this? Thanks for any hint!

(I guess this could be easily done using a DrawingBrush, I'm just wondering whether this could also be done using a RadialGradientBrush)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to make a "bullseye" of absolute sizes, consider overlaying Ellipses in a grid instead of trying to use a brush.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Ellipse}">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
   <Ellipse Width="100" 
            Height="100"
            Fill="Salmon" />
   <Ellipse Width="50" 
            Height="50"
            Fill="Red" />
   <Ellipse Width="25" 
            Height="25"
            Fill="Black" />
</Grid>
```

Since they are all in the same grid (column and row are both 0 by default, but you could set them), and have their horizontal and vertical alignments set to stretch, they will simply overlap.  Be sure to put the biggest one first, of course.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply! Still wondering how the absolute Brush.MappingMode works. Guess I'll make a new post for that. Oh and I will select one solution as answer, thanks!

Comment: MappingMode is for the StartPoint and EndPoint.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientbrush.mappingmode.aspx

Answer (score 5):

If you really, really want to do this, you can repeat the colors that you want at the offsets that you want.

For example:

```
            <RadialGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Black" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.25" Color="Black" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.25" Color="Red" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="Red" />
                <GradientStop Offset="0.75" Color="Salmon" />
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Salmon" />
            </RadialGradientBrush>
```

That way, it will fill Black to Black from 0 to 0.25, Red to Red from 0.25 to 0.75, and Salmon to Salmon from 0.75 to 1.0.

Since the offsets match, there is no "room" for the Gradient to blend.

Comment: Thanks for that hint, works great! The size / length / width.. of the gradients is relative, is there a way to specifiy it in device independent units, e.g. the black circle shall be 30 units?

Comment: Ok theres Brush.MappingMode and you can set it to absolute, but I just don't get it how to work with it... Could someone please post some example code? Thanks!

Comment: See next answer, for formatting reasons (and feel free to select one as The Answer).  :)